# texで線だけで区切るの表を作成しているときに，二重線（空のセルみたいなもの？）が発生する

Tags: latex

texで線だけで区切るの表を作成しているのですが、
作成した表に，二重線（空のセルみたいなもの？）が発生します。

作りたいファイルとしては，excelで線だけで囲んで作るような表です。
しかし、４列目に二重線（空のセルみたいなもの？）ができてしまうので、それを消したいです。
現時点では、
http://www.latex-cmd.com/fig_tab/table01.html
のリンク先を参考にしているのですが、表に何かの付け加え方くらいしかわかりませんでした。
以下に、texファイルの表の部分を示します。

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{2015年におけるStack Overflowの質問件数}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r||r|} \hline
       & タグ名(XML) & 説明 \\ \hline
      質問id & id & 投稿順に付与される質問のid \\ \hline
      質問id & id & 投稿順に付与される質問のid \\ \hline
      質問id & id & 投稿順に付与される質問のid \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:no_ans_question}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: まぁ、`\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r||r|}` となっていますのでそうなりますね。`\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ほとんど回答に近いコメントありがとうございます。
できました。
可能であればで良いので、lやcやｒの意味等
その行の詳細を教えていただいてもよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: `l` は左寄せ(left)、`c` は中央配置(center)、`r` は右寄せ(right)になります。`|` は罫線で、`{|l|c|r|}` は1列目を左寄せ、2列目を中央、3列目を右寄せにして、列の間に罫線を引くことになります。Vertical bar を2回重ねると(`||`)、2重線になります。